# Finding needle in a haystack (error when comparing two objects with .equals)

Tags: java

Trying to find a string `"needle"` in an Object array. But using `.equals` to compare gives me an error. But using `==` works. Why?
I thought I had to use `.equals` to compare objects/strings.

Code that runs with `==`

```
public class ANeedleInTheHaystack_8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object[] haystack2 = {"283497238987234", "a dog", "a cat", "some random junk", "a piece of hay", "needle", "something somebody lost a while ago"};
        Object[] haystack1 = {"3", "123124234", null, "needle", "world", "hay", 2, "3", true, false};
        System.out.println(findNeedle(haystack2));
        System.out.println(findNeedle(haystack1));
    }

    public static String findNeedle(Object[] haystack) {

        for(int i = 0 ; i < haystack.length ; i ++) {
            if(haystack[i] == "needle") {
                return String.format("found the needle at position %s", i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

Out put

```
found the needle at position 5
found the needle at position 3
```

---

and code that doesn't run with `.equals`

```
public class ANeedleInTheHaystack_8 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        Object[] haystack2 = { "283497238987234", "a dog", "a cat", "some random junk", "a piece of hay", "needle",
                "something somebody lost a while ago" };
        Object[] haystack1 = { "3", "123124234", null, "needle", "world", "hay", 2, "3", true, false };
        System.out.println(findNeedle(haystack2));
        System.out.println(findNeedle(haystack1));
    }

    public static String findNeedle(Object[] haystack) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < haystack.length ; i ++) {
            if(haystack[i].equals("needle")) {
                return String.format("found the needle at position %s", i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }

}
```

out put

```
found the needle at position 5
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NullPointerException
    at ANeedleInTheHaystack_8.findNeedle(ANeedleInTheHaystack_8.java:15)
    at ANeedleInTheHaystack_8.main(ANeedleInTheHaystack_8.java:10)
```

Seems like I am only getting an error when I am comparing with `null`. Can `.equals` compare an object with `null`?

Comment: `.equals` can only be used if you know the calling object is not null. You could make it work in your code by switching to `"needle".equals(haystack[i])` since `"needle"` is obviously always going to be non-null

Comment: Use `Objects.equals` instead. It will handle `null` values gracefully.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your method findNeedle like this:

```
    public static String findNeedle(Object[] haystack) {
        for(int i = 0 ; i < haystack.length ; i ++) {
            if("needle".equals(haystack[i])) {
                return String.format("found the needle at position %s", i);
            }
        }
        return null;
    }
```

You can't call method of null, but equals method can check if a object is equal to null.

Answer (score 0):

> *using == works. Why? I thought I had to use .equals to compare objects/strings.*

In most scenarios, you probably *should* use `.equals()` compare objects and strings, but it is totally valid (and sometimes exactly what you want) to use `==`.

Using `==` will compare the object references – do these two variables point at the same underlying object? Using `.equals()` will evaluate whether the objects are equivalent.